# Internet access authentification in browser after connecting to network

Tags: networking, wifi

I need to set up Wi-Fi, where user after connecting to Wi-Fi will have to login to connect to the internet.

Like after he connects to Wi-Fi, he opens page in web browser. He will be automatically redirected to login page, where he must enter credentials and then he will get internet access.

I think that the router will somehow redirect the traffic over server in LAN and then some kind of SW running on the server will do this, but what SW should I use? I don't know how this is called, so I couldn't googled anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find it, it's called `Captive portal`, here is a tutorial how to do it: http://blog.trifork.com/2013/01/15/building-a-captive-portal-controlling-access-to-the-internet-from-your-network/